# Determine if a function is a PRG when PRG concatenated with Seed?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

I am a newbie in Cryptography and have trouble to solve the following question.

> Let $G: \{0,1 \}^n \rightarrow \{0,1 \}^{l(n)}$ be a PRG and $x
>  \epsilon \{0,1 \}^n$. Determine if the function $Z: \{0,1 \}^n
>  \rightarrow \{0,1 \}^{(l(n)+n)}$ s.t. $Z(x) := G(x)||x$ is also a PRG.

My first assumption was that it is a PRG, because the concatenation of the PRG Output G(x) as pseudorandomstring with a uniformly distributed random String x is also a random string. Hence, it can also not be distinguished by an adversary.
Furthermore l(n)+n > n, so Expansion is also ok.

How can i prove that? My idea is a Reduction that if there is a distinguisher D who breaks Z(x) would break also G(x) with non-negl probability, which contradicts the initial assumption that G(x) is a PRG.

Am i on the right track or completely lost?

Comment: So your function Z is outputting the seed together with the random values derived from it? The algorithm is known as well.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, exactly. But what do you mean with "algorithm is known as well"?  G ist not specified any further. Therefore, if I need to give a counterexample for the case that Z is not a PRG, I can design G however I want.

Comment: No, this is not usually correct. We generally assume Kerckhoff's principle: any security is not in the algorithm but in the key or - in this case - seed. You can design $G$ however you want, but you should assume that any adversary knows the algorithm. In other words: you cannot assume $G$ to generate any secrecy besides the seed $x$. Now what would happen if you first generate a key and then an IV using $Z$?

Comment: Hint: Is there perhaps some kind of test / distinguisher that can check whether a given random-looking string is coming from $Z$ or just plain random? Assume the adversary can compute $G$ as well.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The only idea that i have is that an adversary can get the key/seed from the output of Z by performing a cut (because adversary knows the algorithm and knows that the key has a length of n). Then he can input this "key" into the function and check whether it is the same output or not. As far as I know, a PRG is deterministic. And in this case he even knows the key. Right track?

Comment: Yeah, that's the right track. Generally it should not be possible to derive the state of the RNG as it would leak information about all the other bytes in the stream.